# How to swap the order of specific words in a string?

Tags: java, string, swap

I have a string:

```
String test = "This is a test string of many words and more";
```

Also I have a list of unique words that needs to be swapped:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("is", "test", "words", "more");
```

the list contains words in the correct order extracted from original string. Number of words to reverse order is varying.
The result must look like this: all of words in a list are reversed and put in original string

```
"This more a words string of many test and is"
```

Splitting by space would not work because this is a general solution to specific problem.

Comment: This sounds like homework perhaps.  Have you tried writing any Java code yourself yet?  This site tries to not be a free code writing service.

Comment: When you say "reverse", do you mean "swap"? What if those words appear more than once? What if they don't appear in the same order in `test` and `words`?

Comment: No, this is no homework. This is a personal issue I have troubles with. The words to replace and string to replace are guaranteed to have unique words, and the order in a given list is always correct. And by "reverse" I mean change order of words, Like if I have A B C D E F, and i have to replace order of B, C, F, the result must be A F C D  E B

Comment: Show what you've done so far and describe what's not working in your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "This is a test string of many words and more";
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList("is", "test", "words", "more");
    int size = words.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
        String firstWord = " "+words.get(i)+" ";
        String secondWord = " "+words.get(size - 1 - i)+" ";
        String temp = "####";
        test = test.replace(firstWord, temp);
        test = test.replace(secondWord, firstWord);
        test = test.replace(temp, secondWord);
    }
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Comment: Well, the output of this code is `Thmore more a words string of many test and is`, which is not exactly what OP requested.

Comment: Edited to get the proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    String test = "This is a test string of many words and more";
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList("is", "test", "words", "more");

    String split[] = test.split(" ");

    int listIndex = 0;
    int lastListIndex = words.size() - 1;
    int lastIndex = split.length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        String word = split[i];

        if (word.equals(words.get(listIndex))) {
            for (int h = lastIndex; h >= 0; h--) {
                String word1 = split[h];
                if (word1.equals(words.get(lastListIndex))) {
                    split[i] = word1;
                    split[h] = word;
                    lastListIndex--;
                    listIndex++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (listIndex == lastListIndex) break;
        }

    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        String str = split[i];
        if (i == split.length - 1) sb.append(str);
        else sb.append(str).append(" ");
    }

    String output = sb.toString();

    System.out.println(output);
```

I've tested it.
If you need explaining, ask in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach

```
private static void swapWords() {
    String test = "This is a test string of many words and more";

    List<String> words = Arrays.asList("is", "test", "words", "more");
    Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        mappings.put(words.get(i), words.get(words.size() - 1 - i));
    }

    var output = Arrays.stream(test.split(" "))
            .map(word -> mappings.getOrDefault(word, word))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    System.out.println(output);
}
```